# Restrict value on decimal TryParse

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have following code:

```
Decimal.TryParse("1.0e-50", NumberStyles.Float,CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat, out val)
```

I want to restrict it to e-45. Is there a way to do this without using regular expressions? I googled it but only best way i got was regex.

Comment: You should really just parse it as a decimal without bounds checking it, and then check the min/max values *after* you've parsed it into a numeric value.

Comment: @Servy - Can you please put that as an answer so i can mark is as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really just parse it as a decimal without bounds checking it, and then check the min/max values after you've parsed it into a numeric value.  Trying to do the bounds checking on the string, before parsing it, is just asking for trouble; it'll be way more work, and more error prone.

Comment: Having one more problem it is returning value of 0 if i do e-45? So how can i check if it does not return a value?

Comment: @NoviceMe Your problem is that `Decimal` doesn't have enough significant digits to represent that number.  You could use a `double` if you're willing to deal with the floating point rounding errors, or you'll need to use a 3rd party numeric type that can support that larger range.

Comment: so there is no way to do this using decimal than?

Comment: @NoviceMe Not just using a decimal normally, no.

Answer (score 2):

Parse the value first and just compare it with a min/max value afterwards because there is no better way than regex to check how big the decimal value contained by the string is. All in all, parsing is much cleaner, efficient and I also would guess that it is faster.